# Simple join gives unnecessary rows,How to get join properly with only matches in both tables

Tags: sql, join

```
Table 1
Field1 Field2  
AA 20
AA 20
AB 12
AC 13

Table2
field3 field4
AA 20
AA 20
AC 13
AD 23
AW 21
```

output required:

```
newfield field2 field4
AA   20 20
AA   20 20
AC   13 13
```

I used:

```
 select field1 as newfield, t1.field2,t2.field4
      from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.field1=t2.field3
```

This does not give the required output,Please let me know how to get the required output,Many thx in advance
I cant use distinct as I need the given output, these are not duplicates,other column values are different for these rows

Comment: Why do you have duplicated rows in your database? Don't you like primary keys?

Comment: What is the incorrect output you are getting?

Comment: @OrbMan: He's getting four copies of the first row instead of just two.

Comment: @LS: What database are you using?

Comment: Since you've said that other columns may be different, four rows is the correct number you should be getting back for AA (1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2).

Comment: Having said that, if you're not selecting other values from these rows (such as the PK), why would you want *any* duplicates?

Comment: @Mark, yeah I understand the dupes, but not sure why it is ok to have 2 dupes but not 4...?

Comment: Oh, because there are other columns OP did not bother showing...sigh.

Comment: @OrbMan: Because each row is used once from each table. At first I didn't understand this either, but I think I do now. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: wow, I hate when people do what I'm about to do but...if this is the kind of query you need, why are you storing your data this way?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: OK, now I think I now what you're trying to do. You want each row in the first table to match with at most one row in the second table. If you are using MS SQL, Oracle or PostgreSQL then you can use ROW_NUMBER to uniquify your rows:

```
SELECT Field1 AS newfield, Field2, field4
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1 ORDER BY field2) AS rn
     FROM Table1) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field3 ORDER BY field4) AS rn
     FROM Table2) AS T2
ON T1.Field1 = T2.field3 AND T1.rn = T2.rn
ORDER BY Field1
```

Result:

```
'AA', 20, 20
'AA', 20, 20
'AC', 13, 13
```

If you are using MySQL you can simulate ROW_NUMBER using variables:

```
SELECT Field1 AS newfield, Field2, field4
FROM
(SELECT
    Field1,
    Field2,
    @rn := CASE WHEN @last = Field1 THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
    @last := Field1
FROM Table1, (SELECT @rn := 0, @last = NULL) AS vars
ORDER BY Field1) AS T1
JOIN
(SELECT
    Field3,
    Field4,
    @rn := CASE WHEN @last = Field3 THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
    @last := Field3
FROM Table2, (SELECT @rn := 0, @last = NULL) AS vars
ORDER BY Field3) AS T2
ON T1.Field1 = T2.field3 AND T1.rn = T2.rn
ORDER BY Field1
```

Result:

```
'AA', 20, 20
'AA', 20, 20
'AC', 13, 13
```

Comment: @Peter Lang: So did I on my first attempt! @LS: Be careful... if there is extra data on the row, this solution might not do what you expect.

Comment: Oh, I see I gave the same answer as you already had, except that I am preserving rows from `Table1` whereas you are favoring `Table2`. Requirements still unclear!

Comment: ok, that seems needlessly complicated.  Other answers on this thread seem simpler.

Comment: @moleboy: I also had an answer like that before, but I think it is not what the OP wants. I think he wants min(n,m) rows in the output if there are n rows in table 1 and m rows in table 2, and each row should only be used zero or one times (there might be other columns in the real tables).

Comment: yeah, I see now.  Its the 'other columns' that creates the issue with my solution.  I get the unique joins, based on just the example data.  Other columns would cause problems.
But, as I said on my comment on the OP, if this query is required, then you really shouldn't store data this way (and yes, I hate when people tell me that as well, as if I always have the power to go back and redesign the database...)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select field1 as newfield, t1.field2,(SELECT DISTINCT field4 from table2 t2 where t1.field1=t2.field3) as field4
      from table1 t1)
      where field4 is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is what you are looking for, but your data sample is too small to really tell what is going on:

```
select field1 as newfield, t1.field2, t2.field4
from table1 t1 
inner join (
    select distinct field3, field4 
    from Table2
) t2 on t1.field1 = t2.field3
```